# Optimized Way To Download CSV From MySQL JPA application

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, opencsv

I have table which has around a 300k rows in MySQL connected with Hibernate JPA application. We need to provide a way to download this data in csv from our UI application.

If we query the data using hibernate and build a csv using opencsv csv writer it's very slow and takes long time to generate the csv.

What should be the best approach to download csv faster? Is there a way in mysql where we can directly generate the csv on disk using some query and return the csv to user? Or any other faster approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file can be generated easily by just using FileWriter and adding comma after every column and saving file with csv extension

```
private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

        writer.append("DisplayName");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Age");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("YOUR NAME");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("100");
        writer.append('\n');

        // generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now read from DB and for each record keep on adding in file

EDIT:-

```
SELECT display_name,age FROM user INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/user.csv' FIELDS     TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Using above query you can directly download csv

Comment: That I know. I was thinking if there is a direct way to download CSV from query.

Comment: SELECT display_name,age FROM user
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/user.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


Using above query you can directly download csv

Comment: OK. Awesome. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if it solved your problem.In this way it will help others looking for the same problem.

Comment: I tried running your solution. But I am getting write error on my disk due to permission. I am having Ubuntu server, does the mysql user need some permission to write on disk?

Comment: Finally after solving the permissions problem I was able to run it. Thanks. This made the csv download solution very fast.